# how do i unit test an Ember Router?

Tags: unit-testing, ember.js

i've looked at the unit testing for Ember.Router and noticed that it does not define any connectOutlets() on its routes.

however, i want to understand how i should unit test my own extension of the Router in my app.  obviously i don't want all the dom elements instantiating for a unit test.  is there a way to unit test the Router in isolation?  some sort of 'headless' or 'testing' flag?

or should i just concentrate on integration testing and put my router tests in there?

```
 App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a relatively recent version of Ember, a change was made to automatically initialize applications on DOM ready.  As you're seeing, this can cause problems during testing.  The way to opt-out of that automatic initialization is to set `autoinit: false` on your `Ember.Application`.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
    autoinit: false
});

/* ... */

App.initialize();
```

Comment: furthermore in my talking with ken, you can mock out the connectOutlet() function of the respective controller inside the Route.connectOutlets() function.